Scaling of faces with individual center
I want to scale the sizeX and the sizeY of four faces to 0

So I applied this operation on each one of them:

But it's not working:

The result that I want:

I am using Blender 3.6.9.

To scale the faces in the way you want, you would also have to use the Center for the scaling.
In your case, the center is the position of the left or right edge.
So if you access the individual faces via indices, you can do the same with the edge and obtain its position with the Evaluate at Index node.
In this example, the indices of the faces are 12 and 17, as well as 5 and 23:

The scaling center of these are at edges 4 and 2:

If you then formulate this with geometry nodes, the solution could look something like this:

(Blender 3.6.11+)
